# How can I add the current url parameters to the href of an <a> when clicking link to external site

Tags: javascript, html, web, event-handling

we use instapage as a tool for landing pages and they strip url parameters from links if users click on  tags with external links. I want to preserve the location.search though.

I tried using this script here, but it doesn't work at all - as in, the parameters still get removed unless they are specified in the href link.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + window.location.search;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

Anything obvious I am missing here?

Comment: Why is the event listener attached to the window? Using `target` may not do what you think. Try clicking a span inside a link and I think you’ll find `target` to be the span

Comment: @evolutionxbox where else should it be attached to? The listener should be present on the entire page. The script is also checking for the href of the clicked element and the links on the Site are all <a> tags.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. You could listen for a click on the links instead. `document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => addEventListener('click', ...))`

Comment: I tried this (and some other solutions using this) but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: It might that the parameters are removed by the page load? Why not amend the HREFs using JavaScript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is exactly the solution that just worked out for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by just modifying the hrefs on page load instead of trying to add the parameters onClick. Here is the code - also respecting urls that already have parameters in them.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('[href^="http"]').forEach((element) => {
      var hrefString = element.getAttribute('href')
      if(hrefString.includes('?')) {
        element.setAttribute('href', hrefString + window.location.search.replace('?', '&') )
      } else {
        element.setAttribute('href', hrefString + window.location.search)
      }
    })
});
```